# Jsp doesn't show swf File

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a Webproject with JavaEE (Tomcat, Jsp, Servlets)

I want to Show a SWF in my Jsp Page (game.jsp). For doing this i Need a Servlet, which is this:

```
package src;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import util.SystemEnviroement;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ImageServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/ImageServlet")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public ImageServlet() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    String imageName = request.getParameter("imageName");


    SystemEnviroement env = new SystemEnviroement();

        String filename = env.gameFolder + "/" + imageName;

        // Get the MIME type of the image
        String mimeType = sc.getMimeType(filename);
        if (mimeType == null) {
            // sc.log("Could not get MIME type of " + filename);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return;
        }

        // Set content type
        response.setContentType(mimeType);

        // Set content size
        File file = new File(filename);
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

        // Open the file and output streams
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, count);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();


}
```

}

My game.jsp is this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ page import="util.*"%>
<%@ page import="constants.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<jsp:include page='header.jsp'/>
<% 
String gamename = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
int index_name = gamename.lastIndexOf("/");

gamename = gamename.substring(index_name+1,gamename.length());



%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


</head>
<body style="background-color:#630592; 
      background-repeat:no-repeat;"
>


<div class="body">

        <%

        try {
            //SystemEnviroment wird im Konstruktor gesetzt
            SystemEnviroement en = new SystemEnviroement();
            String datei = en.imageViewPath + gamename +".swf";
    %>



    <div class=gameswf>
        <a> <embed src='<%=datei %>'  > </embed> </a>
    </div>


    <%  
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So i have debugged my Project, all thinks Looks well. But after calling the Servlet, the game.jsp doesn't Show the SWF File.

The htmltext(sourcecode) also Looks well, but the game.jsp doesn't Show the SWF File:

```
<div class=gameswf>
        <a> <embed src='http://localhost:8080/Game/imageView?imageName=3-pandas.swf'>   </embed> </a>
    </div>
```

If i call this URL in my running web Project `"http://localhost:8080/Game/imageView?imageName=3-pandas.swf"`, i can sell the SWF File and all is fine.

Do you have any idea why the jsp page doesn't Show my SWF File. If i go to the Internet explorer add ons, i can also see that Shockwave Flash Object is loading.

Thanks for helping !

This is the Image from ie 11 network monitoring feature from developer Tools:

[image]

Comment: `localhost` in URl will make client to look on their localhost, it won't work unless you expect server and client on same host

Comment: Did you try using network monitoring feature from developer tools and find out what is getting returned in response?

Comment: Did U stated fom woking example?

Comment: Why dont you simply put the swf file above the WEB-INF folder so it will be served statically?

Comment: @CuriousMind: i have updated my post, and added an image

Comment: @Stefan: i have a question, if i do the SWF avove the Web-Inf Folder, what happens with the perfomance of my web application. It'the same if i put the Folder outside or its worst ? thanks

Comment: @javajava are you getting the same trace while invoking JSP?

Comment: I tested your servlet with a simple swf file, on a html5 page and it shows up.

Comment: @CuriousMind: this was the trace if i invoke jsp

Comment: Where does "SystemEnviroment.imageViewPath()" point to?

Comment: @Stefan: it's a class variable this.imageViewPath = "http://localhost:8080/Game/imageView?imageName=";

Comment: @Stefan: Can you maybe send me your example, then i can compare it with my Workspace ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create an html file (with html extension) and write the code you expect from the jsp to generate.
Once you make the swf work in html file, it will be a piece of cake to develop the proper jsp code in order to generate that html file.